# map is not showing correct location in my blackberry applications

Tags: blackberry, dictionary

I am calling blackberry map by converting the real coordinates as you can see

```java
public static void showMap(String latitude,String longatude){
    try {   
        int specailLatitude  = (int)(Double.parseDouble(latitude))*100000;
        int specailLongatude = (int)(Double.parseDouble(longatude))*100000;
        MapView mapView=new MapView();
        mapView.setLatitude(specailLatitude);
        mapView.setLongitude(specailLongatude);
        mapView.setZoom(07);
        MapsArguments arg=new MapsArguments(mapView);
        Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, arg);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        CustomUtility.showToast("Map is not available "+e.getMessage());
    }
 }// end of the showMap
```

but problem is this its now showing correct location , it always shows same location in UAE , please help that i am converting correctly ?

Comment: what string values are you passing in for `latitude` and `longatude`, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Is your current location in the UAE? There's a bug in OS 7 maps where it takes you to your current location instead of the requested lat/long.  I am not aware of any workarounds, unfortunately.